# Crome crash, "Update Sync Passphase" - Browser hacked?

Tags: google-chrome, security

I went to a link at simplyhired.com and my browser crashed.

When I reload it, I get the message, "Sync Error: Update sync passphrase"

This might just be an innocent crash, but it sure sounds like a hack attempt.

Do I need to change every password I have everywhere, cancel all my credit cards, move to a new address, and change my appearance?

Comment: No, Some Google services are just currently down.

Answer (score 4):

Google's services are having bit of [a problem now](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en). That's causing Chrome to crash, specifically, [the sync part](https://gist.github.com/4251938). So no, it's not a hack attempt.